# Libgdx how to repeat my event when the button is pressed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So i have a button on my app and when i press it the event triggers but i want it to repeat triggering as long as the button is pressed and not released

```
        button.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            System.out.println(" still pressed");
            return true;
        }

    });
```

So here when i press the button i get " still pressed" but then i have to release the button and press it again to get the text "still pressed " to show in the console.
But i want it when i press the button and NOT release it will show multiple times in the console as long as i don't release it.

Answer (score 0):

if (button.isPressed()) System.out.println("still pressed");

Comment: No the event needs to be kept triggering so repeat all the code thats is inside as long as i press the button not just 1 time

Comment: I know. Make your own subclass of button and override the act method to do that. Or just put my statement above in your screen's render method.

Comment: its not good i even uses the isOver() on the desktop version it works+- but oon an android phone i have to dubbel tap the button to work and i just want when i go over it or pres it it starts repeating util i move my finger away.

Comment: I don't know why but this approach triggers an infinite loop and crashes my app. Even if i have released the button.